# Exporting models to Adobe Dimension

Tags: export, import, units, dimensions

I have a question about changing units when exporting to Adobe Dimension. When I export basic cube 2 m x 2 m x2 m from Blender 2.8. as a OBJ file and import it in Adobe Dimension, the cube has 2 cm x 2 cm x 2 cm. It is one hundred times smaller. Why doesn't have it same dimension? If I try to exchange the cube with FBX file, the scale of the cube is same ( 2 m ). I supose that universal format for exchange models between 3D aplication is OBJ file. Any explanation?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file :
"OBJ coordinates have no units[...]"

This means that it is up to the importing application to decide what a unit is. It could be yards, kilometres, centimetres etc. If you know that Adobe Dimension uses centimetres then you need to export it as such.

You can set the scale to 100 in the obj exporter for instance.

The obj file format can be opened with a text editor to review how the object is exported.

Comment: If I set up Scene Units Meters in Adobe Dimension (same like in Blender) and import the cube, the dimension is 0.02 m x 0.02 m x 0.02 m (in Blender 2 m x 2 m x 2 m). It looks that problem is a scaling to 1% of original size.

Comment: The scene unit will not do anything to the actual size. It's a cosmetic change. Blender is doing what it is should do. Blender will export one meter as one unit until otherwise instructed. Adobe have their paid staff to help you with Dimension.